# Fixed user interface elements for cardboard

Tags: google-cardboard, google-vr

I want create fixed user interface elements like "time remaining until the end of the level".

[time remaining element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbYLE.png)

How should I make it to show it correctly in stereo camera

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called non-diegetic UI and is a bit of an antipattern. The recommended way of doing this is to do a diegetic UI - something that is positioned somewhere in the scene, preferably on something that would make sense in real life - for example a computer screen on a console that is in sight.

Still, if you want something in a forced location, it will work well. To do this you should render it in 3d and rotate/position it so that it's always in front of your camera. For example if you would be using the Unity game engine, you could create this UI element as a world space canvas and parent it to the main camera.

Comment: I use unity. I try create new UI element (for example image). Set render mode to "Screen space camera". But I can choose for "render camera" only "Left camera" or "Right camera"

Comment: As I have earlier said, set the canvas to world space. You have set to screen space. Look at this tutorial by Unity: [User Interfaces For VR](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/virtual-reality/user-interfaces-vr).

Comment: Thank you:) it's usefully link